# Best Method to Find Embedding Similarity Between Array of Items to One Single Item

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-networks

Say I have an array of items purchased together and I have different attributes of these products purchased together.

```
X_1a = [product_id_1,product_id_2,product_id_3]
X_2a = [product_id_2, product_id_3]
X_3a = [product_id_3, product_id_4, product_id_5, product_id_6]

X_1b = ["product desc 1", "product desc 2", "product desc 3"]
X_2b = ["product desc 2", "product desc 3"]
X_3b = ["product desc 3", "product desc 4","product desc 5", "product desc 6"]

X_1c = ["country_origin_for_product1", "country_origin_for_product2", "country_origin_for_product3"]
X_2c = ["country_origin_for_product2", "country_origin_for_product3"]
X_3c = ["country_origin_for_product3", "country_origin_for_product4","country_origin_for_product5", "country_origin_for_product6"]
```

I then create 3 embedding layers and train a tensor flow model:

```
embedding#1 : [w11, w12, w13, w14]
embedding#2 : [w21, w22, w23, w24]
embedding#3 : [w31, w32, w33, w34]

model = Model([input1,input2,input3])
```

Given some new customer and combination of products/attributes that are bought

What is the best way to recommend the *single* most similar product?

```
[product_id_1,product_id_5,product_id_6] = product_id_x
```

Note: I would convert the ids in the first layer to strings.

Comment: One approach is, you could take the element-wise similarity for each product across all three embeddings, average them and take the product with the highest similarity.

Comment: @thushv89, do you think each embedding layer be describing the same thing?

Comment: So if I'm correct you have a fixed set of products right. And the embeddings for these are learned using different sources. Intuitively I feel like regardless of the source product recommendation should follow similar trends (at least for high-level category of the product). So in that case, I feel like average should work. The other option is to take the majority vote.

Comment: Also, if you trust one source more than the other and have some weighting scheme, you can use weighted average

Comment: I need to revise my question. X1b is dependent on X1a and really come from the same source.